# Approximating arccos(a/(a+x)) for the sake of simplfying an integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, estimation

I recently tried to evaluate

$$\int e^{\beta\arccos(a/(a+x))}dx$$

(everything constant except $x$)

and got a complicated answer involving a hypergeometric series with complex arguments.

Can anyone come up with a way of turning $f(x)=arccos(a/(a+x))$ into a function that, when put in the place of $f(x)$ makes the original integral easier? NOTE: the approximation only needs to be good for small $x$ (note that a taylor series at 0 involves $arccos'(1)$ etc (which is $-\infty$) so I need something different).

Thanks!

Comment: How do you use this integral afterwards? Because it might be an option to write $e^x = \sum_{k \ge 0} x^k / k!$ and use a linear approximation or something, I don't know how precise you need to be.

Comment: genius, try and make this the answer. Using partial sum helps here